# moving the browser shell to top right corner

Tags: java, swt

Using java, i created a shell and then opened the browser inside the shell, i want to move the shell to top right corner of the screen. I am trying to use setBound function, but it is not working.. how do i find the coordinates of the top right screen. 
How to set the shell to a specific location
Code:

```
{
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
     browser.setBounds(  x, y, 200 ,200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the top right of the screen by getting the bounds of the [`Monitor`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FMonitor.html):

```
final Monitor monitor = Display.getCurrent().getPrimaryMonitor();
final Rectangle monitorBounds = monitor.getBounds();
final Point topRight = new Point(monitorBounds.x + monitorBounds.width, monitorBounds.y);
```

If you want to account for multiple monitors, you can use [`Display#getMonitors()`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#getMonitors--), and implement some logic to pick the `Monitor` that you care about.

You're on the right track for positioning the `Shell`. You can use the `topRight` `Point` from above, and subtract the width of the `Shell` to keep it on-screen. Alternatively there is a [`Shell#setLocation(Point)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#setLocation-org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point-) method that you can use.

For example:

```
public class ShellLocationTest {

    private final Display display;
    private final Shell shell;

    public ShellLocationTest() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NONE);
        final Point shellSize = new Point(400, 200);
        shell.setSize(shellSize);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final Rectangle monitorBounds = display.getPrimaryMonitor().getBounds();
        final Point shellLocation = new Point(monitorBounds.x + monitorBounds.width - shellSize.x, monitorBounds.y);
        shell.setLocation(shellLocation);
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new ShellLocationTest().run();
    }

}
```